# d3.js barchart not quite like I want it

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I'm doing a simple bar chart with d3.js (version 4.1), and I have followed an example from the official documentation. This is my jsfiddle:

[My current barchart](https://jsfiddle.net/cp1bt1yh/)

This is my code:

html:

```
<div class="diagram-wrapper">
   <div class="barchart">
       <div class="header">
        <h2>High score</h2>
       </div>
       <div class="content">

      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Js:

```
var data = [{
 points: 50,
 name: "gunnar"
}, {
 points: 100,
 name: "herp"
}, {
 points: 500,
 name: "Jacob"
}];

var width = 420,
 barHeight = 20;

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
 .range([0, width]);

var chart = d3.select(".diagram-wrapper div.barchart div.content")
 .append('svg')
 .attr("width", width);

x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
 return d.points;
 })]);

chart.attr("height", barHeight * data.length);

var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
 .data(data)
 .enter().append("g")
 .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
   return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")";
 });

bar.append("rect")
 .attr("width", function(d) {
   return x(d.points);
 })
 .attr("height", barHeight - 1);

bar.append("text")
 .attr("x", function(d) {
   return x(d.points) - 3;
 })
 .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
 .attr("dy", ".35em")
 .text(function(d) {
   return d.points;
 });
```

But all of the examples I can find are from version 3, or they use TSV og SCV data format... What I want is something like this:

[Example of what I want](https://www.dashingd3js.com/lessons/basic-chart-bar-chart)

So basically my questions are as follows:

- How do I turn the bars vertical instead of horizontal?
- How do I add the names below the bars in the x-axis?
- How do I add some values to the y-axis, that the points then relate to?

Sorry for all the questions, I really did investigate the docs, but I can't quite wrap my head around it when there's a leak of working examples and blogposts in 4.1

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to "flip" an horizontal bar chart to a vertical bar chart... you have to pretty much change almost all the code. Here I'll show the basic steps (Please note that I'm not modifying your code, but creating a new one).

First, the data is the same. Then, we append the SVG:

```
var width = 400, height = 500;

var svg = d3.select("#chart")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);
```

After that, we define the scales. The x axis is now qualitative, while the y axis is quantitative:

```
var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(data.map(function(d){ return d.name}))
  .range([100, width])
  .paddingInner(0.2)
  .paddingOuter(0.2);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){ return d.points})])
  .range([height - 40, 10]);
```

Then, we bind the data:

```
var bars = svg.selectAll(".bars")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect");
```

With the data bounded we append the rectangles. This is the tricky part: notice how we calculate `x`, `y`, `width` and `height`:

```
bars.attr("x", function(d){ return xScale(d.name)})
  .attr("y", function(d){ return yScale(d.points)})
  .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
  .attr("height", function(d){ return (height - 40) - yScale(d.points)})
  .attr("fill", "steelblue");
```

And then, the axes:

```
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

svg.append("g").attr("transform", `translate(0,${height-40})`)
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(100,0)")
  .call(yAxis);
```

And the fiddle shows the code working: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/o1cer41s/

PS: there are some magic numbers in the code. Also, I'm using a template literal that won't work if you use IE.

Comment: Thanks alot!.. thats exactly what i was looking for and just awesome!